# Retrieve submitted data of Form which was Eagarly loaded

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am eagarly loading data into my controller's action as:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var temp = db.Parents.Include(x => x.Childrens).FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ID==1);
            return View(temp);
        }
```

And in View I am showing the Editor for them as:

```
   @model DataLoadingDemo.Models.Parent
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit","Parent"))
    {    
    @foreach (var item in Model.Childrens)
                {
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => item.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => item.Name)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.Name)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
}
```

When I am submitting the Form, on that time I am not getting the "Children" into my [Httppost] action which is as::

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="ID,Name")] Parent parent, List<Children> item)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(parent).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(parent);
        }
```

I am just getting "Parent Data" and not the Eagarly loaded Childrens.
Please help me on this.

Comment: The `Children` should be _in_ the `Parent`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Entity Framework.
Check out this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

First of all, make sure that you have a Parents record with ID equal to 1, and make sure that it has Childrens records. 
If both these conditions are true then, I suspect that the FirstOrDefault clause is looking for the item where the Childrens ID is equal to 1. 
You want to be sure that it is looking for the item where the Parents ID is equal to 1.

Try changing the order of your clauses, like this.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var temp = db.Parents.Where(x=>x.ID==1)
             .Include(x => x.Childrens).FirstOrDefault();
        return View(temp);
    }
```